# Angular, jquery and MVC Ajax forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin that I can use to insert HTML retrieved from a server using Ajax into a page.  This plugin is specifically designed to insert the response from an MVC controller into an angular page.

I have the plugin almost working.  All of my element ng-model bindings work correctly.  However, my ng-hide and ng-show bindings are not actioned on the inserted HTML elements.

My plugin looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dynamic = function (html) {
        // Insert the Html in the DOM
        this.html(html).each(
            function() {
                // Is angular installed on the page?
                if (!window.angular) return;

                // Get the angular scope for this control
                var scope = angular.element(this).scope();

                // Get the contents of the element
                var contents = $(this).contents();

                // Bind the controls
                var injector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
                injector.invoke(
                    ["$compile", function ($compile) {
                        scope.$apply(
                            function () {
                                // Associate the HTML and the scope
                                $compile(contents)(scope);
                            }
                        );
                    }]
                );
            }
        );

        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why would you need jQuery for this and not do it with angular?

Comment: Whoops...because I got so focused on a solution I forgot the most obvious answer.  MUCH easier to do in angular.  Thanks